# Equilibrium solutions of a differential equation and their nature

Tags: applications

I need some help with the following the differential equation
$$
\dot{x}=x^{4}-3x^{3}+2
$$
I found that the equilibrium solutions are $x \approx 1, 2.9196, -0.45982+-0.68817i$. If you someone could check that I did it correctly and also if these solutions are stable or unstable, thanks!

Comment: The equilibrium solution is when $x'=0$ so in this case when $x^4-3x^2+2=0$.

Comment: Yes, $ x^{4}-3x^{3}+2=0 $. However, I also need help with finding the nature of those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation 
$$
\dot x=x^4-3x^3+2
$$
 is an [autonomous equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#Definition), and an equilibrium solution is a constant solution: $x(t)=c$ .

Clearly we have such a solution if $\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot x=0$, so the equilibrium solutions are the roots of the equation
$$
x^4-3x^3+2=0
$$
The roots find in OP are correct ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20x%5E4-3x%5E3%2B2%3D0)) and the $x-$ axis of the graph in this link can be used as a [phase line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)) for the differential equation. So we see that $x=1$ is a stable solution and $x \approx 2.9$ is unstable.